# How to split the digit in php

Tags: php

How can I achieve number 4,7,8 separately if there is a given variable: `$i=478` such that I can store `$j=4,$k=7,$l=8` in PHP. Is there a function?

Comment: if its is a variable then must be `string`

Answer (score 7):

```
$i = 478;
$stri = (string)$i;
$j = $stri[0];
$k = $stri[1];
$l = $stri[2];
```

Comment: php will throw notices if `$stri[2]`  is not set in case if there is only two digits

Comment: Ah, gotcha. In this case we know it's set ;) Iterating would indeed be a more elegant solution though, but the PO asked for $j, $k and $l.

Comment: @MeLight: can you help me find average of this if I given input 478 it should be 4+7+8/3. please

Comment: @Sanks Raut if you want an average you will have to iterate, use Shakti's solution from below to sum all numbers and then divide the result.

Comment: @diEcho then you will have to iterate and use an array and not $j, $k and $l ;)

Answer (score 5):

You should cast the number to a string and then [str_split](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php) it:

```
$numbers = str_split((string)$number); // or
list($a, $b, $c) = str_split((string)$number); // but this might throw a notice if $number is 12 or 8 or something
```

Comment: do we really need to cast to string? str_split($number) seems to work fine

Answer (score 2):

Use type case and convert number to string

```
$i=478 ;
$i= (string)$i ;
```

String can be accessed as array hence you can do

```
echo $i[0]; //to access 4
```

you can iterate as array as well using loops

```
$len=strlen($i);
for($j=0; $j <= $len; $j++)
{
   echo $i[$j]."<br>";
}
```

Comment: if `i` is an `integer` or `string` then  `count()` will always return 1, u must use `strlen`

Answer (score 0):

try

```
 $n=567;
 $x = (string)$n;
 for($i=0;$i<strlen($x);$i++)
 { 
    echo "<br/>".$x[$i];
 }
```

#### UPDATE:

to find the **average**

```
for($i=0;$i<strlen($x);$i++)
     { 
        echo "<br/>".$x{$i};
        $t+=(int)$x[$i];
     }
echo  "average:". $t/strlen($x);
```

Comment: Avoid using `{` you should always use `[` instead to denote string elements

Comment: we can treat string as an array

Comment: The way you are accessing the element of string is deprecated  `$x{$i}` you should always access like `$x[$i]`. For more info please refer to manual

Comment: @shakti Singh read this :http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/53015-quick-intro-to-php-strings/

Comment: @diEcho: It is old and from 2008 now it is 2011 technology changes frequently. Take your time. If I am false no problem will take back downvote and also give upvote. If you see in the link above he is iterating string what he used.

Comment: @shakti Singh  read here also in [php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.complex)

Comment: String s may also be accessed using braces, as in $str{42}, for the same purpose. However, this syntax is deprecated as of PHP 5.3.0. Use square brackets instead, such as $str[42].

Comment: I am not such type of boy http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/php-34/$string%7B$i%7D-deprecated-652708.html    http://bytes.com/topic/php/answers/389756-no-more-access-characters-strings-php-6-a

Comment: I am not fighting with you but wanted to let you know the new facts and you are taking this in another way sorry if I said anything wrong

Comment: @Shakti singh..same here i m bit aggressive. Sorry..tun to apne sahar ka aadmi hai yaar wese bhi ;)