# How to sum a set of values from a form in PHP?

Tags: php

I have a simple form and a submit button. After pressing the submit button, get the values (they will be numbers) and calculate the `sum`. And again calculate the sum of individual digits stored in `sum`.

A better explanation: `1+2+3+4=10` where 1,2,3 and 4 are user inputs from the form. And the sum 10 has to be split-ted and summed again as `1+0=1`. And this would be my final result. So far I did the task where it gives me the first sum. I don't know what to do to display the second result which I want to be the finale.

```
<?php 
$a='';
$sum='';
$total='';
if (!isset($_POST['submit'])) {

echo " ";
}
  else  {
        $a = array($_POST['textfield'],$_POST['textfield1'],$_POST['textfield2'],$_POST['textfield3'],$_POST['textfield4'],$_POST['textfield5'],$_POST['textfield6'],$_POST['textfield7'],$_POST['textfield8'],$_POST['textfield9'],$_POST['textfield10'],$_POST['textfield11'],);
                for ($i=0; $i<=12; $i++) {

        $sum= array_sum($a);

        $total= ;

        }


  }



         echo "sbora e: $total "; 
?>
```

Comment: How do you arrive at the second sum? Where does `1` and `0` come from?

Comment: well they should take values from the $sum

Comment: Yes, but which values? Do you mean it should take the result and add them together? What if the answer > 99?

Comment: yes i want to take the value of the first result if it is 99 then in the second result it has to calculate them 9 + 9 wich is 18 does that make sence sorry for my english not from around :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5729853/how-to-split-the-digit-in-php

Comment: And so a result of 100 from the first sum should yield 1 as the second result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$total = array_sum(str_split($sum));
```

Using Artefacto's [method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3232531/2588457).

---

On another note,

```
$a = array($_POST['textfield'],$_POST['textfield1'],$_POST['textfield2'],$_POST['textfield3'],$_POST['textfield4'],$_POST['textfield5'],$_POST['textfield6'],$_POST['textfield7'],$_POST['textfield8'],$_POST['textfield9'],$_POST['textfield10'],$_POST['textfield11'],);
```

can be written as,

```
$a = array();
for ($i = 0; $i <= 11; $i++){
     if (isset($_POST["textfield_$i"]))
     array_push($a, $_POST["textfield_$i"]);
}
```

if the names of the fields are:

```
textfield_0, textfield_1, textfield_2...
```

Answer (score 1):

So you want to build the cross sum of your first result:

```
$result2 = 0;
//cast integer to string
$strTotal = (string) $total;
//loop over "chars" and add them to your second result
for($i=0; $i < strlen($strTotal); $i++)
{
    $result2 += $strTotal{$i};
}
```